# Is $\frac {x^2 + 5x}{x} = x+5$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We are graphing functions in class and the function $f(x) = \frac {x^2 + 5x}{x}$, came up and our teacher simplified it to $x+5$ and graphed that with a hole in the function at $x=0$.

I started wondering, how in algebra can we say that $\frac {x^2 + 5x}{x} = x+5$, when the graphs of each function are not equal?

Thanks

Comment: $\dfrac{x^2+5x}x=x+5$ where $x\ne0$.

Comment: One can treat them as formal expressions or as functions. As functions of course they (a priori) have different domains so would be different functions and have different graphs. (One can of course artificially restrict the domain of $x+5$ in order to have an equality of functions.) But in the setting of formal algebraic expressions that kind of thing doesn't matter. It's a little bit of abstract algebra hidden in intermediate algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed **invalid** to write "$\frac{x^2+5x}{x} = x+5$". In general, a lot of people are imprecise and never specify properly what objects they are talking about. In this case, what is $x$? Once you answer that question right, you get a true statement:

> $\frac{x^2+5x}{x} = x+5$ for any real $x \ne 0$.

This means that you can plot the graph of $y = \frac{x^2+5x}{x}$ by following the graph of $y = x+5$ for all reals $x \ne 0$. For $x = 0$, of course $\frac{x^2+5x}{x}$ is undefined so we leave a hole there.

Answer (score 3):

The key here is that the domain of the function $f$ is *not* all real numbers.  It's $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$ (meaning all real numbers except $0$).  So once you know that it should be clear that $\frac{x^2+5x}{x}$ is exactly equal to $x+5$ **on that domain**.

If we wanted to specify that, we'd write $f: \Bbb R \setminus \{0\} \to \Bbb R$ is given by $f(x)=x+5$.  Then we'd immediately see that the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$ and the codomain$^\dagger$ is $\Bbb R$.  But often mathematicians and teachers are a little lazy and will just expect you to realize that sometimes when they write $A=B$, they mean $A=B$ **on the largest domain where both $A$ and $B$ are defined**.

$^\dagger$: If you've never heard of a codomain, don't worry about it exactly.  It's related to the range of the function, but it's not super important to know to understand basic algebra.